Debugging RCU stalls on Ubuntu Server 22.04, 5.15-realtime
I am trying to isolate CPUs on an AMD EPYC 8534PN (64C/128T). Unfortunately, I see the RCU stalls and the server crashes over and over. And I am not really sure what I am doing wrong.
The crashes only happen when the server is under load. Usually, I am running build jobs and some tasks with RT priorities there (integration tests). But from my understanding, by using rcu_nocbs=8-63,72-127 irqaffinity=0-7,64-71 rcu_nocb_poll in grub, setting IRQBALANCE_BANNED_CPULIST=8-63,72-127, and moving the remaining rco's over to the houskeeping group with tuna -t rcu* -c 0-7,64-71 -m should avoid this, shouldnt it? I expect no rcu to be executed on the isolated cores anymore.
The errors I am seeing looking like the following:
RCU stalls
This is a part of the dmesg output:
Apr 22 00:08:37 hp-epyc kernel: rcu: INFO: rcu_preempt detected stalls on CPUs/tasks:
Apr 22 00:08:37 hp-epyc kernel: rcu:         Tasks blocked on level-1 rcu_node (CPUs 48-63): P497/2:b..l
Apr 22 00:08:37 hp-epyc kernel:         (detected by 53, t=2940082 jiffies, g=1051549, q=30752212)
Apr 22 00:08:37 hp-epyc kernel: task:ksoftirqd/53    state:R  running task     stack:    0 pid:  497 ppid:     2 flags:0x00004000
Apr 22 00:08:37 hp-epyc kernel: Call Trace:
Apr 22 00:08:37 hp-epyc kernel:  <TASK>
Apr 22 00:08:37 hp-epyc kernel:  __schedule+0x238/0x5e0
Apr 22 00:08:37 hp-epyc kernel:  ? asm_sysvec_reschedule_ipi+0x1b/0x20
Apr 22 00:08:37 hp-epyc kernel:  preempt_schedule+0x60/0x80
Apr 22 00:08:37 hp-epyc kernel:  preempt_schedule_thunk+0x16/0x18
Apr 22 00:08:37 hp-epyc kernel:  rt_mutex_slowunlock+0x280/0x2f0
Apr 22 00:08:37 hp-epyc kernel:  ? try_to_wake_up+0x307/0x670
Apr 22 00:08:37 hp-epyc kernel:  rt_spin_unlock+0x3e/0x50
Apr 22 00:08:37 hp-epyc kernel:  __hrtimer_run_queues+0x3a0/0x3c0
Apr 22 00:08:37 hp-epyc kernel:  hrtimer_run_softirq+0xa6/0x110
Apr 22 00:08:37 hp-epyc kernel:  __do_softirq+0xc9/0x2cc
Apr 22 00:08:37 hp-epyc kernel:  run_ksoftirqd+0x30/0x80
Apr 22 00:08:37 hp-epyc kernel:  smpboot_thread_fn+0x1d3/0x2d0
Apr 22 00:08:37 hp-epyc kernel:  kthread+0x191/0x1b0
Apr 22 00:08:37 hp-epyc kernel:  ? smpboot_register_percpu_thread+0xe0/0xe0
Apr 22 00:08:37 hp-epyc kernel:  ? set_kthread_struct+0x50/0x50
Apr 22 00:08:37 hp-epyc kernel:  ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30
Apr 22 00:08:37 hp-epyc kernel:  </TASK>

Complete output
Based on the lscpu -p output I came up with the following isolation scheme:
housekeeping & IRQs: 0-7,64-71
isolation: 8-63,72-127

Systemd is configured as following:
sudo systemctl set-property user.slice AllowedCPUs=0-7,64-71
sudo systemctl set-property system.slice AllowedCPUs=0-7,64-71
sudo systemctl set-property init.scope AllowedCPUs=0-7,64-71

The IRQs are banned from the isolated cores in /etc/default/irqbalance:
IRQBALANCE_BANNED_CPULIST=8-63,72-127
IRQBALANCE_ONESHOT=0

And I have moved the rcuo's via tuna -t rcu* -c 0-7,64-71 -m to the housekeeping group.
Grub is configured as following:
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.15.0-1032-realtime root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ro quiet splash selinux=0 enforcing=0 nmi_watchdog=0 crashkernel=auto softlockup_panic=0 nosoftlockup audit=0 mce=off tsc=nowatchdog skew_tick=1 default_hugepagesz=1GB hugepagesz=1G hugepages=12 iommu=pt amd_iommu=on nohz_full=8-63,72-127 rcu_nocbs=8-63,72-127 irqaffinity=0-7,64-71 nohz=on rcu_nocb_poll numa_balancing=disable transparent_hugepage=never nosoftlockup rcu_nocb_poll processor.max_cstate=0 kthread_cpus=0-7,64-71

OS: Ubuntu Server 22.04.4 LTS 
Kernel: 5.15.0-1032-realtime 
CPU: AMD EPYC 8534PN 64-Core Processor
I really don't understand whats going wrong here. I appreciate any kind of help! Thank you!
Edit:
I was able to stabilize the server. I had some help by this article (unfortunately, subscription only). These are the steps I have taken:
The first step was to disable irqbalanced. I found there is a bug that silently fails to enforce the IRQBALANCE_BANNED_CPULIST parameter. I tried to use IRQBALANCE_BANNED_CPU, but this parameter was already deprecated in the version we are using. So I disabled irqbalanced completely.
In the article it says "In the past, the ksoftirqd/N threads handled the timer softirq tasks, along with the work for the other softirqs.". I couldn't find any ksoftirqd processes, instead I only found the softirqs which have also appeared in the kernel logs.
This is why I have moved the ksoftirqd threads to the highest priority to avoid them starving on the CPU.
x=8
y=63
for i in $(seq $x $y) ; do tuna -t "ksoftirqd/$i" -p fifo:99; done
a=72
b=127
for i in $(seq $a $b) ; do echo "$i"; tuna -t "ksoftirqd/$i" -p fifo:99; done

I have also applied the rcutree.kthread_prio=99 kernel parameter to the kernel command line to set the priority of the  RCU rcuc/N and rcub/N threads to 99.
To give a complete picture, I am running RT workloads with priorities up to 50 on the server through Kubernetes. I also run unit and build tests in parallel to the RT workloads.
Can someone confirm the above assumption that ksoftirqd still handels timers and work ob Ubuntu is still correct? I couldnt find much about it researching.
Another question I have regarding this topic is, why are not all rcu workloads moved properly to the housekeeping group? I don't want to use isolcpus, which I guess would help with this. Is there another way to move the interrupts completely so the isolated cores are free for RT workloads? Thanks in advance!

Please find your kernel configuration file (either in the root dir of the kernel source tree or in /boot) and then post the ouput of grep RCU .config

The requested output after the changes mentioned above: https://pastebin.com/Nrfn0L2a
